# IP address detected for Vandalism in Wikipedia

Tags: ip-address

While browsing through Wikipedia recently I noticed a message regarding article vandalism using my IP address. My ISP is Hathway and I am a normal home user. I also use tor browser for torrenting. Is this case of hacking ? Or is this a case of shared IP address that the ISP shares same IP address to all ?

P.S Some kids in our colony use those illegal network sniffers to use free WiFi and as a measure I have created an Access Control list in router. Is it possible they have overridden that ?

P.S.S I haven't put any password in Router login page (It is in it's default setting admin login)

Comment: What kind of 'access port' list do you mean?

Comment: Access control list it will allow only specified mac address to access wifi

Answer (score 0):

The error means that someone using the IP address you are using (as Wikipedia sees it) was vandalising articles. Unless you have a static address, This in no way implies your systems were involved.

Yes, if your ISP uses CGN (Carrier grade NAT), or your IP changes whenever your router restarts or periodically the problem is likely another Hathaway user.

Yes, it is possible for someone to crack your WiFi password and use your Internet without your permission. An access control list would not stop them as they could emulate your MAC address. You can harden WIFI networks, but generally blocking Mac addresses won't stop technical users (but it could slow them down or cause noticeable effects on legitimate users)

If you can't control your router properly, lock it down to only pass traffic to a VPN provider and use a VPN.(also, change the default password - but do it over a PC connected via Ethernet)

Lastly, don't assume that sniffing software is illegal - while "digitally breaking and entering" is, using sniffing software us typically not only legal but necessary in diagnosing a raft if issues.

Comment: Wouldn't they need the physical device spoof MAC or did they just get it from sniffing  packets ?

Comment: MAC addresses can be read from sniffing packets - physical access is not necessary if they can break WiFi encryption.  Something I missed - is this happening in normal browsers or just for browser?

Comment: It's happened the first time and it got me worried